# Python script with parallel statistical model breaks when run locally

Tags: python

I have a Python script that was developed on the servers of Kaggle.com. I would like to run it locally, but it generates errors and never completes when I try.

I believe it has something to do with the parallel nature of one of the statistical algorithms, but I can't figure out what's required of me to set it up properly on my local computer.

Here's the script:

```
'''
An open source script from Kaggle, developed by a couple dozen people. Runs fine there.
'''

if __name__ == '__main__':    

    import time
    start_time = time.time()

    print("Starting imports")
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
    from sklearn import pipeline, grid_search
    from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
    from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion
    from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
    from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, make_scorer
    from nltk.stem.porter import *
    stemmer = PorterStemmer()
    import re
    import random
    random.seed(2016)

    print("Reading in data")
    df_train    = pd.read_csv('train.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
    df_test     = pd.read_csv('test.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
    df_pro_desc = pd.read_csv('product_descriptions.csv')
    df_attr     = pd.read_csv('attributes.csv')
    print("pull brand")
    df_brand    = df_attr[df_attr.name == "MFG Brand Name"][["product_uid", "value"]].rename(columns={"value": "brand"})
    print("dr_train.shape[0]")
    num_train   = df_train.shape[0]
    df_all = pd.concat((df_train, df_test), axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    df_all = pd.merge(df_all, df_pro_desc, how='left', on='product_uid')
    df_all = pd.merge(df_all, df_brand, how='left', on='product_uid')

    print("Functions")
    def str_stem(s): 
        if isinstance(s, str):
            s = s.lower()
            s = s.replace("'","in.") 
            s = s.replace("inches","in.") 
            s = s.replace("inch","in.")
            s = s.replace(" in ","in. ") 
            s = s.replace(" in.","in.") 

            s = s.replace("''","ft.") 
            s = s.replace(" feet ","ft. ") 
            s = s.replace("feet","ft.") 
            s = s.replace("foot","ft.") 
            s = s.replace(" ft ","ft. ") 
            s = s.replace(" ft.","ft.") 

            s = s.replace(" pounds ","lb. ")
            s = s.replace(" pound ","lb. ") 
            s = s.replace("pound","lb.") 
            s = s.replace(" lb ","lb. ") 
            s = s.replace(" lb.","lb.") 
            s = s.replace(" lbs ","lb. ") 
            s = s.replace("lbs.","lb.") 

            s = s.replace(" x "," xby ")
            s = s.replace("*"," xby ")
            s = s.replace(" by "," xby")
            s = s.replace("x0"," xby 0")
            s = s.replace("x1"," xby 1")
            s = s.replace("x2"," xby 2")
            s = s.replace("x3"," xby 3")
            s = s.replace("x4"," xby 4")
            s = s.replace("x5"," xby 5")
            s = s.replace("x6"," xby 6")
            s = s.replace("x7"," xby 7")
            s = s.replace("x8"," xby 8")
            s = s.replace("x9"," xby 9")
            s = s.replace("0x","0 xby ")
            s = s.replace("1x","1 xby ")
            s = s.replace("2x","2 xby ")
            s = s.replace("3x","3 xby ")
            s = s.replace("4x","4 xby ")
            s = s.replace("5x","5 xby ")
            s = s.replace("6x","6 xby ")
            s = s.replace("7x","7 xby ")
            s = s.replace("8x","8 xby ")
            s = s.replace("9x","9 xby ")

            s = s.replace(" sq ft","sq.ft. ") 
            s = s.replace("sq ft","sq.ft. ")
            s = s.replace("sqft","sq.ft. ")
            s = s.replace(" sqft ","sq.ft. ") 
            s = s.replace("sq. ft","sq.ft. ") 
            s = s.replace("sq ft.","sq.ft. ") 
            s = s.replace("sq feet","sq.ft. ") 
            s = s.replace("square feet","sq.ft. ") 

            s = s.replace(" gallons ","gal. ") 
            s = s.replace(" gallon ","gal. ") 
            s = s.replace("gallons","gal.") 
            s = s.replace("gallon","gal.") 
            s = s.replace(" gal ","gal. ") 
            s = s.replace(" gal","gal.") 

            s = s.replace("ounces","oz.")
            s = s.replace("ounce","oz.")
            s = s.replace(" oz.","oz. ")
            s = s.replace(" oz ","oz. ")

            s = s.replace("centimeters","cm.")    
            s = s.replace(" cm.","cm.")
            s = s.replace(" cm ","cm. ")

            s = s.replace("wayy", "way")
            s = s.replace("milimeters","mm.")
            s = s.replace(" mm.","mm.")
            s = s.replace(" mm ","mm. ")

            s = s.replace("°","deg. ")
            s = s.replace("degrees","deg. ")
            s = s.replace("degree","deg. ")

            s = s.replace("volts","volt. ")
            s = s.replace("volt","volt. ")

            s = s.replace("watts","watt. ")
            s = s.replace("watt","watt. ")

            s = s.replace("ampere","amp. ")
            s = s.replace("amps","amp. ")
            s = s.replace(" amp ","amp. ")

            s = s.replace("whirpool","whirlpool")
            s = s.replace("whirlpoolga", "whirlpool")
            s = s.replace("whirlpoolstainless","whirlpool stainless")

            s = s.replace("  "," ")
            s = (" ").join([stemmer.stem(z) for z in s.split(" ")])
            return s.lower()
        else:
            return "null"

    def str_common_word(str1, str2):
        words, cnt = str1.split(), 0
        for word in words:
            if str2.find(word)>=0:
                cnt+=1
        return cnt

    def str_whole_word(str1, str2, i_):
        cnt = 0
        while i_ < len(str2):
            i_ = str2.find(str1, i_)
            if i_ == -1:
                return cnt
            else:
                cnt += 1
                i_ += len(str1)
        return cnt

    def fmean_squared_error(ground_truth, predictions):
        fmean_squared_error_ = mean_squared_error(ground_truth, predictions)**0.5
        return fmean_squared_error_

    RMSE  = make_scorer(fmean_squared_error, greater_is_better=False)

    class cust_regression_vals(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
        def fit(self, x, y=None):
            return self
        def transform(self, hd_searches):
            d_col_drops=['id','relevance','search_term','product_title','product_description','product_info','attr','brand']
            hd_searches = hd_searches.drop(d_col_drops,axis=1).values
            return hd_searches

    class cust_txt_col(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
        def __init__(self, key):
            self.key = key
        def fit(self, x, y=None):
            return self
        def transform(self, data_dict):
            return data_dict[self.key].apply(str)

    def fmean_squared_error(ground_truth, predictions):
        fmean_squared_error_ = mean_squared_error(ground_truth, predictions)**0.5
        return fmean_squared_error_

    RMSE  = make_scorer(fmean_squared_error, greater_is_better=False)

    #if adding features consider any drops on the 'cust_regression_vals' class
    df_all['search_term'] = df_all['search_term'].map(lambda x:str_stem(x))
    df_all['product_title'] = df_all['product_title'].map(lambda x:str_stem(x))
    df_all['product_description'] = df_all['product_description'].map(lambda x:str_stem(x))
    df_all['brand'] = df_all['brand'].map(lambda x:str_stem(x))
    df_all['len_of_query'] = df_all['search_term'].map(lambda x:len(x.split())).astype(np.int64)
    df_all['len_of_title'] = df_all['product_title'].map(lambda x:len(x.split())).astype(np.int64)
    df_all['len_of_description'] = df_all['product_description'].map(lambda x:len(x.split())).astype(np.int64)
    df_all['len_of_brand'] = df_all['brand'].map(lambda x:len(x.split())).astype(np.int64)
    df_all['product_info'] = df_all['search_term']+"\t"+df_all['product_title'] +"\t"+df_all['product_description']
    df_all['query_in_title'] = df_all['product_info'].map(lambda x:str_whole_word(x.split('\t')[0],x.split('\t')[1],0))
    df_all['query_in_description'] = df_all['product_info'].map(lambda x:str_whole_word(x.split('\t')[0],x.split('\t')[2],0))
    df_all['word_in_title'] = df_all['product_info'].map(lambda x:str_common_word(x.split('\t')[0],x.split('\t')[1]))
    df_all['word_in_description'] = df_all['product_info'].map(lambda x:str_common_word(x.split('\t')[0],x.split('\t')[2]))
    df_all['ratio_title'] = df_all['word_in_title']/df_all['len_of_query']
    df_all['ratio_description'] = df_all['word_in_description']/df_all['len_of_query'] #hack-r.com
    df_all['attr'] = df_all['search_term']+"\t"+df_all['brand']
    df_all['word_in_brand'] = df_all['attr'].map(lambda x:str_common_word(x.split('\t')[0],x.split('\t')[1])) #linkedin.com/in/datasci
    df_all['ratio_brand'] = df_all['word_in_brand']/df_all['len_of_brand']
    df_brand = pd.unique(df_all.brand.ravel())
    d={}
    i = 1
    for s in df_brand:
        d[s]=i
        i+=1
    df_all['brand_feature'] = df_all['brand'].map(lambda x:d[x])
    df_all['search_term_feature'] = df_all['search_term'].map(lambda x:len(x))
    df_train = df_all.iloc[:num_train]
    df_test = df_all.iloc[num_train:]
    id_test = df_test['id']
    y_train = df_train['relevance'].values
    X_train =df_train[:]
    X_test = df_test[:]
    print("--- Features Set: %s minutes ---" % round(((time.time() - start_time)/60),2))

    rfr = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 175, n_jobs = 1, random_state = 2016, verbose = 0)
    tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 1), stop_words='english')
    tsvd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=25, random_state = 2016)
    clf = pipeline.Pipeline([
            ('union', FeatureUnion(
                        transformer_list = [
                            ('cst',  cust_regression_vals()),  
                            ('txt1', pipeline.Pipeline([('s1', cust_txt_col(key='search_term')), ('tfidf1', tfidf), ('tsvd1', tsvd)])),
                            ('txt2', pipeline.Pipeline([('s2', cust_txt_col(key='product_title')), ('tfidf2', tfidf), ('tsvd2', tsvd)])),
                            ('txt3', pipeline.Pipeline([('s3', cust_txt_col(key='product_description')), ('tfidf3', tfidf), ('tsvd3', tsvd)])),
                            ('txt4', pipeline.Pipeline([('s4', cust_txt_col(key='brand')), ('tfidf4', tfidf), ('tsvd4', tsvd)]))
                            ],
                        transformer_weights = {
                            'cst': 1.0,
                            'txt1': 0.5,
                            'txt2': 0.25,
                            'txt3': 0.0,
                            'txt4': 0.5
                            },
                    n_jobs = -1
                    )), 
            ('rfr', rfr)])
    param_grid = {'rfr__max_features': [24], 'rfr__max_depth': [29]}
    model = grid_search.GridSearchCV(estimator = clf, param_grid = param_grid, n_jobs = -1, cv = 2, verbose = 20, scoring=RMSE)
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)

    print("Best parameters found by grid search:")
    print(model.best_params_)
    print("Best CV score:")
    print(model.best_score_)

    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    y_train_pred = model.predict(X_train)
    print("--- Running Predictions for Training Data --")
    pd.DataFrame({"id": id_test, "relevance": y_pred}).to_csv('test_python_predictions.csv', index=False)
    print("--- Training & Testing: %s minutes ---" % ((time.time() - start_time)/60))
    print("--- Running Predictions for Training Data --")
    pd.DataFrame({"id": id_test, "relevance": y_train_pred}).to_csv('train_python_predictions.csv', index=False)
    print("-- Now Printing Training Data to File --")
    pd.DataFrame({"id": id_test, "Data": X_train}).to_csv('X_train.csv', index=False)
    print("-- Now Printing Testing Data to File --")
    pd.DataFrame({"id": id_test, "Data": X_train}).to_csv('X_test.csv', index=False)
```

Here's the errors:

```
C:\Users\hackr\Desktop\hd>python wc.py

    Starting imports
    Reading in data
    pull brand
    dr_train.shape[0]
    Functions
    --- Features Set: 7.18 minutes ---
    Fitting 2 folds for each of 1 candidates, totalling 2 fits
    Process SpawnPoolWorker-3:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\python35\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 254, in _bootstrap
        self.run()
      File "C:\python35\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "C:\python35\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 108, in worker
        task = get()
      File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\pool.py", line 360, in get
        return recv()
      File "C:\python35\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 251, in recv
        return ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
    AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'cust_regression_vals' on <module '__mp_main__' from 'C:\\Users\\hackr\\Desktop\\hd\\wc.py'>
    Process SpawnPoolWorker-2:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\python35\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 254, in _bootstrap
        self.run()
      File "C:\python35\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "C:\python35\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 108, in worker
        task = get()
      File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\pool.py", line 360, in get
        return recv()
      File "C:\python35\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 251, in recv
        return ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
    AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'cust_regression_vals' on <module '__mp_main__' from 'C:\\Users\\hackr\\Desktop\\hd\\wc.py'>
```

I can't even kill this script without killing the Python processes through the task manager. If I use `ctrl+C` while it's running it spews more errors and shows my Keyboard Interrupt on screen but doesn't stop.

Comment: I finally got this to work, but I still don't understand exactly what the problem was or how I fixed it. I'll add an answer once I figure that out. There were no messages about unmet dependencies, but to better understand the technology in use I installed joblib by itself and tried running some of the example code to see what happened. It ran fine and this installation may have contributed (?) to the script above subsequently working. The only other thing I've changed that I know of was to reduce the max depth of the model.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that your class (specifically `cust_regression_vals` is being defined only inside `if __name__ == '__main__'` which limits it to being defined only when the script is directly executed as the main program and not treated as a module. Definitions generally do not go in such a conditional.

Comment: Depending on what you're doing you may very well need `if __name__ == '__main__'` around your script. But don't put defs and classes inside that if block without good reason.